# How to configure a Django application in a virtual env served by uswgi and started by a systemd service?

Tags: python, django, linux, uwsgi, systemd

I'm trying to configure a basic a Django application served by uwsgi so that it can be started from systemd on a CentoS 7.X server.

So far my SystemD service is started (active and in running state) but application is not reachable on the configured port. Note that application is running inside a Python virtual environment.

- Systemd service is active and running
- uwsgi worker processes are
  active
- socket bind to TCP 8003 is in LISTEN state

**SystemD unit file**

```
# /etc/systemd/system/django_03.service

[Unit]
Description=My Django app
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
User=myuser
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
StandardError=syslog
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /opt/scripts/django/django_03; source django_03_env/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini /opt/scripts/django/django_03/django_03.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**uwsgi configuration file**

```
# /opt/scripts/django/django_03/django_03.ini

[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 5
socket = 127.0.0.1:8003
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

**Django application**

```
# wsgi.py
def application(environ, response):
    response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [b"Test OK (Django 03) !!"]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What web server are you using? You need to have a web server listening to port 80 and proxying the requests to uwsgi your application server.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) will help.

Comment: @dirkgroten: a reverse proxy is not mandatory. uwsgi can operate with a TCP socket (this works): uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8003 --protocol=http -w wsgi. But I need uwsgi to be started as a service using systemd capabilities

Comment: For the record, default uwgsi protocol need to be changed to http in uwsgi configuration file with: protocol = http

Comment: you can answer yourself if you have the correct answer

Comment: @dirkgroten: OK, I'll post a detailled answer. I agree that using a reverse proxy in front of uwsgi is better, leaving uswgi with its default operation mode (binary protocol).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, systemd service is called "django_03", Python virtual env name is "django_03_env", Python application is "wsgi" with a callable named "application".

**1 ] Prerequisites**

Create a root directory for Python code, configuration files and virtual env:

```
mkdir /opt/scripts/django/django_03
```

Create a virtualenv

```
cd /opt/scripts/django/django_03
python3 -m venv django_03_env
```

Start virtualenv

```
source django_03_env/bin/activate
```

Install Django and uwsgi

```
pip install django
pip install uwsgi
```

**2 ] Files**

There are three files to create

1. uwsgi configuration file (INI format): django_03.ini
2. SystemD service unit: django_03.service
3. Python application: wsgi.py

**2.1 SystemD unit file**

```
# /etc/systemd/system/django_03.service

[Unit]
Description=My Django app
Requires=network.target
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
User=myuser
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
StandardError=syslog
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
# Main call: Virtual env is activated and uwsgi is started with INI file as argument
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /opt/scripts/django/django_03; source django_03_env/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini /opt/scripts/django/django_03/django_03.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**2.2 uwsgi configuration file**

```
# /opt/scripts/django/django_03/django_03.ini

[uwsgi]
# "callable": Application entry point, <Python filename without extension: application method name>
module = wsgi:application
# Master process for uwsgi
master = true
# Worker processes for uwsgi
processes = 5
# uwsgi protocol modification
protocol = http
# Socket format X.X.X.X:<port number>
socket = 127.0.0.1:8003

chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

**2.3 Django application file**

```
# /opt/scripts/django/django_03/wsgi.py

# Application callable (main entry point)
def application(environ, response):
    response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [b"Test OK (Django 03) !!"]
```

**III ] Managing application**

Django application can now be started by a regular systemd command:

```
sudo systemctl start django_03
```

Verify systemd service status

```
sudo systemctl -l status django_03
journalctl -u django_03
```

Verify that HTTP socket is listening

```
netstat -ntap | grep 8003
```

Verify HTTP response:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8003
```

Note that by default uwsgi operates with its default transfert protocol which is NOT HTTP. It is not recommended to use uwsgi HTTP socket, the best setup being the use of uswgi default protocol and a reverse proxy in front of it (NGINX, Apache HTTPd). Of course code presented here is far from perfect and might be optimized and tailored to your needs.

Comment: Please note that the `chmod-socket = 664` configuration line is useless, as this example is not using Unix sockets.